# why appended line is being printed every time i run my code in python?

Tags: python, append

I opened a text file in python and tried to append. Now when I read the file that appended text is being printed every time I run the code. I want that text to be appended only once.

This is what I have done

```
myfile=open("C:\\Users\\bhavy\\OneDrive\\Documents\\password.txt","a")
myfile.write("\n NEW LINE") 
myfile.close()
myfile=open("C:\\Users\\bhavy\\OneDrive\\Documents\\password.txt","r")
print(myfile.read())
myfile.close()
```

My output is:

```
 line1
 line2
 NEW LINE
 NEW LINE
 NEW LINE
 NEW LINE
```

I want this "NEW LINE" to be printed only once.

Comment: may be it already contains the `NEW LINE' before you even write

Comment: You must check the last line of the text file and quit if it is already `NEW LINE`.

Comment: Well, if you keep on appending to the same file every time you run the code, the result is not surprising

Comment: @deadshot No, the file initially had only the first two lines

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, it gave only one "NEW LINE". Make sure there is no loop above the given code

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print "NEW LINE" once, you can implement it like below.

```
myfile=open("C:\\Users\\bhavy\\OneDrive\\Documents\\password.txt","a")
myfile.write("\n NEW LINE") 
myfile.close()
myfile=open("C:\\Users\\bhavy\\OneDrive\\Documents\\password.txt","r")
is_new_line_printed = False

for line in myfile.readlines():
    if not "NEW LINE" in line:
        print(line)
    elif "NEW LINE" in line and not is_new_line_printed:
        print(line)
        is_new_line_printed = True
myfile.close()

# Result
# line1
# line2
# NEW LINE
```